# Filter rows in pandas dataframe by dynamically generated values (latest date)

Tags: python, pandas, date, duplicates, filtering

I have a data set with newsletter type, newsletter name, newsletter launch date, and email. Every launch goes over many rows because each email address that received the newsletter launch has its own row.

All the newsletters have at least one launch, but some newsletters have many launches. I want to clean my data set so that I only have the most recent launch of each newsletter. However, the "most recent" date is different for every newsletter.

I had been trying to sort by date descending, and then de-duplicate and keep the first value.

```
df = df.sort_values('timestamp',ascending=False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='newsletter_type','newsletter_name','email'],keep="first")
```

Because this would keep the most recent launch and get rid of the rest. However, I realised that if a user had unsubscribed ten newsletter launches ago, my program would see that as a 'new' email address and keep it.

Is there a good way to do this? 'Speaking' in pseudo-SQL, I would basically like a way to say

`SELECT newsletter_type, newsletter_name, email FROM dataset WHERE launch_date = MAX(launch_date)`.

EDIT: sample data. I do not want the bottom row, but because that email has not been seen before for this newsletter_name, the de-dupe will keep it. I want to know how to tell pandas to keep 'sample' newsletter's 09/07/2020 launch, because it's the latest.

```
campaign_name   newsletter name newsletter type email_md5   timestamp
test5   sample  A   123@    09/07/2020
test5   sample  A   456@    09/07/2020
test5   sample  A   789@    09/07/2020
test5   sample  A   012@    09/07/2020
test5   sample  A   345@    09/07/2020
test5   sample  A   new@    08/07/2020
```

EDIT2:

Sorry I explained this badly. If I de-dupe the below dataset, I will get the 5 July values for the number email addresses = great, but also the abcde@hotmail email address = bad.

I want the 05/07 newsletter rows for newsletter A, and the 04/07 newsletter rows for newsletter B. I know the number email addresses will appear in both newsletter_type variants.

```
Newsletter_type Launch_name Launch_date Email
            
A   5_July_newsletter   05/07/2020  12345@hotmail
A   5_July_newsletter   05/07/2020  67890@hotmail
A   5_July_newsletter   05/07/2020  55555@hotmail
A   1_January_newsletter    05/06/2020  12345@hotmail
A   1_January_newsletter    05/06/2020  67890@hotmail
A   1_January_newsletter    05/06/2020  55555@hotmail
A   1_January_newsletter    05/06/2020  abcde@hotmail
            
B   5_July_newsletter   04/07/2020  12345@hotmail
B   5_July_newsletter   04/07/2020  67890@hotmail
B   5_July_newsletter   04/07/2020  55555@hotmail
B   1_January_newsletter    04/06/2020  12345@hotmail
B   1_January_newsletter    04/06/2020  67890@hotmail
B   1_January_newsletter    04/06/2020  55555@hotmail
B   1_January_newsletter    04/06/2020  abcde@hotmail
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['timestamp'].idxmax()]` works for me, what if you have multiple campaigns do you want the unique from each group? if the first part answered your Q let me know there are a few dupes it can be linked too

Comment: I want all email values for the max date for each newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

I would sort by 'launch date' and group by 'newsletter name' (if that is the unique type one want to save one of each fore). This would return only the lates of each unique 'news letter'.

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['launch date']).groupby('newsletter name').first()
```

Comment: no need for apply here - also does not match the SQL code at all.

Comment: @Datanovice Agree that apply is not needed but I must have missed what he meant then.

Comment: Can you explain what 'group by' will do here, please?

Comment: @travelsandbooks can you more in depth explain your problem now so I understand it better before we try to solve it. In your example above, how can you know that a email is 'new' and should be sorted out? And from all the rows shown, should only one be removed since that email is 'new'?

Comment: Have updated the question. Sorry I explained it badly!

Comment: To answer your questions - I don't want any emails attached to dates that aren't the max date.

Comment: @travelsandbooks Does this below do the correct thing? In that case I can find a solution without using apply.

df.groupby('Launch_name').apply(lambda x: x[x['Launch_date']==max(x['Launch_date'])]).reset_index(level = 'Launch_name', drop=True)